# Cassandra update multiple rows based on condition

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cql3

I want to update multiple rows in Cassandra if they satisfy my condition with same value(changing flag to false) and my condition field is part of my composite key. But I cannot use whole composite key.

Comment: Would you please demonstrate your problem with an example? Like your table design and what queries you want to do from this table?

Comment: @Chaity 
table :

    id |file         | operation | permission 
    1 |emp.txt | read   | Y 
    2 |emp.txt | write   | Y 
    3 |Hello.txt | read    | Y 
    4 |Hello.txt | write   | F 

If above table has primary_key(id+file) and i want to run query : UPDATE keyspace.fileperm SET id=uuid(), permission='F' WHERE file='emp.txt' IF EXISTS;
I do want to change all records with file 'emp.txt' with flag 'F'.
My current approach is to select the record based on file and then batch update.    </pre>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Cassandra.  `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s are all considered write operations.  And write operations require a **complete** PRIMARY KEY.

Consider this example where I have a partition key of `username` and a clustering key of `transaction_time`: `PRIMARY KEY (username,transaction_time)`.  If I just try to `UPDATE` based on `username`, this fails.

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE rest_transactions_by_user
       SET http_result = 200 WHERE username='Aaron';
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] 
       message="Some clustering keys are missing: transaction_time"
```